# Web Service podem ser ativos, ou apenas passivos (sempre recebem uma requisição)

Tags: web-service

Como se chama um Web Service (Ativo, Middleware, Passivo, ou é sempre Web Service?) que envia dados para um client ou outro Web Service
quando ocorre um evento no sistema ao qual ele pertence?

Exemplo, quando ocorre alteração da situação de um pedido, de "não faturado" 
para "faturado", e quero enviar para o client ou outro Web Service essa alteração. Essa função é de um Web Service, ou é função do client 
ficar verificando a cada X tempo, se houve alteração no pedido?

Ou devo criar outro serviço para esse propósito.

Comment: Pela descrição parece ser *webhook*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aparentemente pela descrição de sua dúvida isto é feito com um webhook;

> O que são webhooks?

Toda vez que um evento acontece na sua aplicação, ele é o responsável por como é feito o recebimento destas informações em tempo real.

> Como funciona?

Em geral os webhooks vão postar os dados para você (como JSON, XML ou até mesmo pelos dados de formulário).

O provedor de serviços é que fara o **handling** dessa informação lhe permitindo muitas vezes escolher como é feito o recebimento destas informações pela sua aplicação.

OBS: hoje em dia a maioria dos frameworks web já vem com uma configuração pré-definida e lhe facilitarão o trabalho(pesquise por laravel echo).

> Cuidados simples ao utilizar um webhook

- Webhooks são responsáveis pela entrega de dados, caso haja algum erro na sua aplicação estes dados podem ser perdidos.
- Saiba como interpretar as mensagens de erro e como o seu provedor lida com as respostas de cada ação, para que você possa adequar seu programa para lidar com eventuais erros de aplicação.
- Tenha em mente que um webhook pode lidar com várias requisições simultâneas, verifique que sua aplicação consegue suportar a escalabilidade sem perder qualidade.

Bom no geral é isso, caso ainda tenha alguma dúvida dê uma olhada neste [link:](https://atendimento.vindi.com.br/hc/pt-br/articles/203305800-Webhooks)

Comment: Usar  Websockets como solução é esse tipo de problema, é uma boa ideia?

Comment: Pelo que entendi, o laravel é feito em PHP, existe algum equivalente bom para .NET?

Answer (score 1):

Ele consegue ser ativo sim, estude [Websocket](https://www.html5rocks.com/pt/tutorials/websockets/basics/), em resumo, Websocket é uma conexão persistente entre o servidos e os clientes, o servidor, sempre que houver uma alteração, pode enviar informações direto para os clientes que estão conectados.

Comment: Acredito que manter uma conexão aberta entre servidor e cliente nesses casos é inviável. Imagina o dia que possuir 100 pedidos pendentes... manter 100 conexões ativas pode ser bastante prejudicial ao sistema.

Comment: Websockets exigem pouquíssimo do servidor, seu protocolo é extremamente leve e, já ví casos de haver 2000 clientes conectados e o servidor praticamente não gasta processamento e nem rede.

Comment: O @GuilhermeBarros tem razão, eu tenho uma aplicação em websocket rodando diariamente com 150+ pessoas conectadas o tempo todo e não passa dos 100mb de RAM gasta pelo servidor.

Comment: Sim eu conheço o Websockets, mas não me parece a solução correta para esse contexto, até tinha pensado nessa possibilidade, mas tinha ficado na dúvida. Agora não imagina que Websockets consumiam tão pouca memória, em comparação com a quantidade de conexões. Qual a resiliência casso ocorre alguma exception/crash grave em alguma conexão?